# VS2017 15.6.5 unable to run/debug tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, nunit, resharper

I am using the latest VS2017 15.6.5 + Resharper, both are the latest. The tests are NUnit tests. It was working fine. But recently, with the new updates of VS2017 and Resharper, I haven't been able to run/debug unit test with Test Explorer for sometime although the tests are discovered. Resharper can run tests, but not able to debug. I disabled resharper, no improvement at all. Any ideas why?